# margins of a paragraph in a table get ignored sometimes and sometimes not. why?

Tags: html, css, iframe

i have a simple table structure

```
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table {
      border-spacing: 0;
      white-space: normal;
    }

    table td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor </p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor </p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor </p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor </p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor </p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor </p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

And the paragraphs inside got their default margins.
But in some cases this margins don't interact with the borders of the table-cell and in some cases they do.

I thought this is because of a strange behaviour of iframes.
So i started the test this locally with 2 test files.
and it looks like this:
https://teamplexus.de/table-test/

[image]

As you can see the margins of the paragraphs inside and outside the iframe don't space up the cells.

But if i recreate this in codepen or jsfiddle it looks different:
https://codepen.io/Killerbear_02/pen/pVYmrN
[image]

here the margins effect the space inside the table-cells.

i don't unterstand this different behaviour.
How can i force my tables to behaviour consistent everywhere?

Comment: in which browser you are testing your code?

Comment: i´m using chrome

Comment: We need to see the one behaving differently

Comment: i uploaded my example here: https://teamplexus.de/table-test/

Comment: there is no doctype declaration on the page .. you are on the quirks mode, add the doctype of html5 `<!DOCTYPE html>` in the most top of your file

Comment: oh boy. that simple. thanks man. love you <3

Answer (score -1):

In body tag style="margin:0px !important;padding:0px !important;"

try it once.